# Metro App - Update mouse pointer position with pen pointers

Tags: wpf, input, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, mouse-cursor

I'm using vc2013 with wfp c#/c++, and target to win8.1 PC & win tablets.

Is there a way to update the position of mouse pointer, which pointer id is 1, with the position of current moved pen pointers which pointer id is 100+ in the PointerMoved event?

We found that for some pen tablets (we have wacom intuos), the pen click (as mouse left) will create a pen pointer type event with an increased id from 100, but the pen buttons click (as mouse right/wheel) will create a mouse pointer type event with id 1 (same as the real mouse). This will cause an issue on 2+ monitors PC (or half half display mode) which is when you:

- Open the app in monitor A,
- Move the real mouse and make its point to another monitor B,
- Use pen to move the pointer back to app in monitor A,
- right click by pen in app's monitor, but a context menu for the monitorB's app will be popped up.

This is because the real mouse pointer (id 1) stop at the boarder of monitor B, even the pen's pointer (id 100+) in monitor A, but click right button still calls real mouse pointer at monitor B.

Is there a way to update the position of mouse pointer, which pointer id is 1, to the position of current moved pen pointers which pointer id is 100+ in the PointerMoved event?

Thanks a lot!